# Emails not being sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, send-email

I've created a new DE based on a sync DE from SF by creating a data filter and a filter activity to create the new DE that should be used for sending emails. I can see the subscribers but when i try to send an email nothing happens. I see a green message that the email was sent but i didn't get any email. Also, the subscribers are not added to all subscribers list.

Is there any known issues when sending emails to DEs that were created that way?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a "sendable" DE meaning that you related either email or subscriberkey when you created the DE? Did you check your Tracking where it shows to how many subscribers the email went to or does it show "0"?

Users will not be added automatically to the All Subscribers list, if you created a DE these users will remain there they are totally separate that is sort of why there are Data Extensions.

Also your new Data Extension what type of data does it contain to how it would map back to All subscriber?

Comment: Yes, it is sendable, Id relates to subscriber on Subscriber Key and it shows 5 subscribers when sending the email. Only thing i can think of that is different is that the source for the DE is a SF sync DE.

Comment: There could be several things at play and I don't have enough information to really give a definite answers but below is some more for you to check

Comment: 1. The Tracking report that you receive after each send has deployed is what you need to look at. If it shows "5 delivered" means that your emails were deployed to your users and if you didn't receive anything it could mean that you have a deliverability issue

2. If your Tracking report shows "0 delivered" that means that something failed during runtime. It could be "validation issues" you may reference personalization strings that you haven't properly mapped in your template since this is a new data extension

Seeing subscribers during a send preview is not the same as deployment

Comment: On the report it says complete and "0" email sent. The email has only text in it. I tried sending to a DE that i created manually and it worked. Could it be related to the way the DE was created?

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to send these emails?

And is there a field with the type "EmailAddress" in the DE you're sending from?

If there is no EmailAddress type field, subscribers that are not present already in All Subscribers will not be sent to.

Comment: I'm trying to send it as a one time email send. And yes there is an EmailAddress type field.

Comment: Hey - were you able to sort this out ? I am facing the same issue currently.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here!! Did you guys find a solution to that?